# How to reimplement the fixModel function of QAbstractProxyModel (Qt)?

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, proxy-classes

I have subclassed `QAbstractTableModel` into `MyModel` and implemented all the needed functions. This works fine. However I would like to filter MyModel.

I've tried `QSortFilterProxyModel` to filter the items. This does the job quite well but when I activate the item and use its position to get the item from source model I get incorrect item. I guess this class is not useful for my purpose because it doesn't provide me any mapping between proxy and source.

So I tried to implement MyProxy which is subclassed `QAbstractProxyModel`. I found example [here](http://wiki.qt.io/Proxy_model_example_code). However the code contains some bugs. I think I understand how it works. What I need to do is reimplement the `fixModel` function according to my needs but in their case they are using `QList<QStandardItem *> list`.

What should I do when using custom model?

What about the parent?

Could you please provide me some example?

Comment: *I've tried QSortFilterProxyModel to filter the items. This does the job quite well but when I activate the item and use its position to get the item from source model I get incorrect item* can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I used filterAcceptsRow to decide if the row should be filtered or not.   It showed me only the items that I wanted. Then I implemented slot for QTableView's signal activated(QModelIndex). When I access the item in this slot I get incorrect item from the model.

Comment: You (correctly) get the index from whatever model's is set on the table view. If the model is your proxy model, use `proxy->mapToSource(index)` to get the index in the original.

Comment: Thanks @peppe. This solved my problem.